# When changing the file for a song in iTunes, the new file is not transferred to my iPod

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod-touch, ipod, music

In my iTunes library, sometimes I replace a low bit rate song that I have with a high bit rate version, such as by using the version found in iTunes Match's database. However, when I sync my iPod with iTunes, the new version of the song is never transferred to the iPod. How can I force the song to transfer? Without needing to restore the entire device, if possible, of course.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but your question is not detailed enough and requires guessing on our side. How do you replace bit rate? with what?

Comment: I subscribe to Apple's iTunes Match service, and what I do is delete a low bit rate song and download the high bit rate version from iTunes Match. I've edited my question to include this information now.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Did you try to delete on iPod?

Comment: One more question, what is the original bit rate of the tracks you are trying to update?

Comment: How do I delete a track on the iPod? I can only remove a track from a playlist, as far as I know. The original bit rate was 128 kbps, and the new one is 256 kbps.